# How to use update_or_create() and F() to create a new record in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

Assuming we have a wallet table with these field: id, user_id, total, freeze, active, update_time.

Each user only have one record in this table, and will be updated all the time.

e.g.

```
{
    id: 1,
    user_id: 100,
    total: 50.5,
    freeze: 0,
    active: 50.5,
    update_time: 2018-07-17 16:43:41,
}
```

When the user earned $5, how could I use the **update_or_create()** method to update the total, freeze and active fields depend on their original value?

```
income = 5.0
Wallet.objects.update_or_create(
    user_id=obj.user.id,
    defaults={
        'update_time': datetime.now(),
        'active': F('active') + income,
        'total': F('total') + income,
    }
)
```

I tried the F() and it works great!

```
{
    id: 1,
    user_id: 100,
    total: 55.5,
    freeze: 0,
    active: 55.5,
    update_time: 2018-08-26 07:12:15,
}
```

However, if the user doesn't have the record in the wallet table which means this is the first time he/she earned money, then something goes wrong:

```
Failed to insert expression "Col(wallet, Wallet.total) + Value(5.0)" on Wallet.total. F() expressions can only be used to update, not to insert.
```

How to fix this if I really wanna use **update_or_create()**?

Need your help, thanks!

Comment: Do you have to use `update_or_create()`? The `F()` expression expects the record to be present so isn't compatible with the create part.

Comment: @WillKeeling Yes, I could do try Wallet.object.update(F() expresssion) excpet Wallet.DoesNotExist Wallet.obejct.create() to accomplish this. But I wanna figure out how to use update_or_create() which would better as the document says "This pattern gets quite unwieldy as the number of fields in a model goes up."  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the **`F()`** function as per your requirement. What you could do is, check for the existence of the object and take action .

```py
user_id = 1
income = 5.0
qs = Wallet.objects.filter(user_id=user_id)
if qs.exists():
    # go fo an update
    qs.update(
        update_time=datetime.now(),
        active=F("active") + income,
        total=F("active") + income,
    )
else:
    Wallet.objects.create(
        user_id=user_id,
        update_time=datetime.now(),
        active=income,
        total=income,
        freeze=0
    )
```

Comment: Why use `update_or_create` if you already know it exists???
`update()` returns number of records updated and that can be used to check if record exists and act accordingly:

`Wallet.objects.filter(user_id=obj.user.id).update(update_time=datetitme.now(), active=F('active') + income, total=F('total') + income) or Wallet.objects.create(user_id=obj.user.id, update_time=datetitme.now(), active=income, total=income)`

Answer (score 3):

Proposed solution by @JPG is affected by a race condition. Depending on a use case you can try smth like this:

```
obj, created = ProductRedirectStats.objects.get_or_create(
        date=date.today(), product_id=product_id, defaults={"redirects": 1}
    )

if not created:
    ProductRedirectStats.objects.filter(date=date.today(), product_id=product_id).update(redirects=F("redirects") + 1)
```

Comment: @bdoubleu your revisions were introducing yet another race condition. I've reverted it back to my original answer.

Comment: [Actually it isn't a race condition](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) and the code above affects every redirect object instead of just the single object.

Comment: @bdoubleu you are right, I've missed filter. Fixed. But anyway you cannot update object as you've proposed. Otherwise you'd overwrite other fields state.